# wtol equivalent in C#

Tags: c#, string, type-conversion

I am translating some code from C++ to C# and there is a function wtol which takes a string input and outputs an integer. Specifically, it takes version string `6.4.0.1` and converts that to 4. How do I do that in C#? I tried `convert.toInt32` but it failed miserably.

Comment: So do you want your output from `6.4.0.1` to be `4` or `6`, `4`, `0`, and `1`?

Comment: `Version.Parse` parses version strings. Is that what you need? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.version.parse.aspx

Comment: Yes, wtol which is same as atol for wide strings

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use (requires .Net 4.0 or higher)

```
Version.Parse("6.4.0.1").Minor
```

This will work pre .Net 4.0

```
new Version("6.4.0.1").Minor
```

Comment: Let me check this. I love one line stuff ;)

Comment: The correct answer - the code is also self-explanatory, which makes it even better.

Comment: @Baldrick *a* correct answer, but definitely better than my answer on readability alone. :)

Comment: Damn, unfortunately, my version is 3.5 .net. It doesnt work there

Comment: Yup, was not aware of that when I posted, but you need at least .net 4.0.

Comment: @TylerDurden: That is a different question and it has been a while since I last used wtol or atoi etc. Are you sure your pointer is pointing where you think it is?

Answer (score 4):

Try this (Assuming you have a number between first and second dot):

```
string myString = "6.4.0.1";

int myInt = Convert.ToInt32(myString.Split('.')[1]);
```

Bit safer method would be (Assuming at least one dot in the string):

```
int myInt = 0;
int.TryParse(myString.Split('.')[1], out myInt);
```

Safest method would be:

```
int myInt = 0;
string[] arr = myString.Split('.');

if(arr.Length > 1 && int.TryParse(arr[1], out myInt))
{
   //myInt will have the correct number here.
} 
else
{
   //not available or not a number
}
```

Comment: You should use `int.Parse` - faster, more efficient.

Comment: That's not safer: when the split results in <= 1 elements, it will throw an `IndexOutOfBoundsException`

Comment: @DavidHaney: I am assuming at least one dot in the string.

Comment: comment it as such then! :)

Answer (score 3):

Use this assuming that you will ALWAYS have a format that is X.X.X.X

```
var test = "6.4.0.1";
var parts = test.Split(new[] { '.' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
int result = int.Parse(parts[1]);
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to use `TryParse` instead of just `Parse`, in case you are taking the version number from a not trusted source.

```
var versionString = "6.4.0.1";
Version version;
if (Version.TryParse(versionString, out version))
{
    // Here you get your 4
    Debug.WriteLine("The version Integer is " + version.Minor);  
}
else
{
    // Here you should do your error handling
    Debug.WriteLine("Invalid version string!"); 
}
```